# Is there a way to count the number of days a columns value took to go from A to B for each month?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with node, value, and datetime columns. I'd like to get the max count of days it took the value to go from 60 to 70 for each month for each node. If the value stayed below 60 or above 70 the value should just be 0. If the value didn't go from 60 to at or above 70 it should be 0.

df:

```py
rng = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', periods=365, freq='D')
df= pd.DataFrame({'Date': rng, 'Val': np.random.randint(50, 80, size=365), 'Node': 'A'}) 
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
```

I've set the index to the node, month, and day, but I can't figure out how to get the count of values between the threshold.

```py
df.set_index(['Node', df.index.month, df.index])['Val'].between(60, 70)
```

I think the answer should just be the max number of consecutive True values in the 'Val' column after the between has been applied for each month.

The output should be a dataframe like this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'Node': 'A', 'Month': 1, 'Count': 3},
    {'Node': 'A', 'Month': 2, 'Count': 5},
    {'Node': 'A', 'Month': 3, 'Count': 0},
    {'Node': 'B', 'Month': 1, 'Count': 5},
    {'Node': 'B', 'Month': 2, 'Count': 3},
    {'Node': 'B', 'Month': 3, 'Count': 2},
    ...
])
```

Comment: do the days have to be consecutive?

Comment: Yes, and it should return the maximum consecutive days

Comment: Was quite complex but I've handled data like this before. Let me know if this answered your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly,

one idea is to use `groupby` with a condtional `cumsum` & `cumcount` to count consecutive days until 70 is reached.

```
np.random.seed(0)
np.random.randint(50, 80, size=365)
rng = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', periods=365, freq='D')
df= pd.DataFrame({'Date': rng, 'Val': np.random.randint(50, 80, size=365), 'Node': 'A'})


df.sort_values('Date',inplace=True)

df['C'] = (df.loc[(df["Val"] > 60) & (df["Val"] <= 70)]
.groupby([df["Date"].dt.month, (df['Val'] == 70).cumsum()])).cumcount() + 1
```

as we only want values that hit 70 in that month we need to set the counts to 0 if 70 was not reached within a given month, we can filter by months and return these into a list then filter by using `isin`

```
months = df.loc[df['Val'] == 70]['Date'].dt.month.tolist()
df.loc[~df['Date'].dt.month.isin(months),'C'] = 0
df1 = (df.groupby([df['Node'],df['Date'].dt.month])['C'].max()
        .reset_index().rename(columns={'Date' : 'Month'}))
    print(df1) 


    Node  Month     C
0     A      1   0.0
1     A      2   6.0
2     A      3   7.0
3     A      4  11.0
4     A      5   7.0
5     A      6   5.0
6     A      7   6.0
7     A      8   0.0
8     A      9   4.0
9     A     10   0.0
10    A     11   9.0
11    A     12   0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
rng = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', periods=365, freq='D')
df= pd.DataFrame({'Date': rng, 'Val': np.random.randint(50, 80, size=365), 'Node': 'A'}) 
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

df1 = df[(df['Val']>=60)&(df['Val']<=70)] # We don't need to consider other values
df1['Month'] = df1.index.month

df2 = df1.groupby(['Month', 'Node']).agg({'Val':['max', 'count']})
df2.columns = df2.columns.droplevel()
df2['count'] = np.where(df2['max']!=70, 0, df2['count']) # If it never gets to 70, assigning count as 0
df2 = df2.reset_index().drop('max', axis=1)

df2
    Month   Node    count
0   1   A   15
1   2   A   13
2   3   A   14
3   4   A   10
4   5   A   10
5   6   A   11
6   7   A   8
7   8   A   17
8   9   A   0
9   10  A   12
10  11  A   7
11  12  A   15
```

Basically, counting values in range and assigning zero if it never reaches 70.
You can add a step after to fill in any missing months due to less than value 60

Comment: This is pretty close. However, I'm trying to find the max time it took to go from A to B. Right now this is returning the count it was in range. If the value goes 60, 62, 65, 59, 62, 67, 68, 70 the count value for that month should be 4 because it only took those 4 days to cover the range. The values 60, 62, and 65 should not be counted because it didn't reach the threshold. Also, if it goes 60, 62, 70 then later in the month goes 60, 62, 63, 67, 68, 70 it should favor the longer duration and return 6.